# Certbot renew: nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: nginx, certbot, renewal

Certbot and nginx versions:

certbot installed using [certbot.eff.org](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuxenial-nginx) install guide.

- Certbot version: 0.22.2
- Nginx version: 1.10.3

Getting ssl certificates works fine:

`certbot --nginx`

But, in renewal of cerbot certificated

`certbot renew --dry-run`

nginx fails to start causing:

`nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

I have tried changing post-hook and pre-hook in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*com.conf/`

- commenting `installer=nginx`
- changing authenticator to nginx and standalone

Adding post and pre hooks in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/pre/` and `/etc/lestencrypt/renewal-hooks/post/` to stop and start nginx service.

Seems nginx is not starting properly or isn't stop properly.
after renewal completes nginx fails with (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nginx error log show:

[image: nginx log image]

Error while certbot renew:
[image: Certbot error log in renewal]

Comment: try to kill the hanging nginx `killall nginx`

Comment: was the nginx stater as "sudo nginx" earlier?

Comment: yes, when starting from bash shell nginx commands works. nginx fails only on ```certbot renew --dry-run```. I think the certbot is read nginx.pid before it starts. as pre-hook already stopped the nginx service.

Comment: @Larry.He killing nginx in certbot pre-hook?

Comment: I manage to get it working by, setting authenticator to nginx, commenting pre_hook and changing post_hook to ```systemctl start nginx``` to ```systemctl restart nginx``` in ```/etc/letsecrypt/renewal/*.com.conf```.

Answer (score 26):

Try to execute:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Then test your nginx configuration file(s) (until you see "*nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful*")

```
sudo nginx -s reload -t
```

**Pay attention on paths to certificates, and other stuff**

and then reload configuration without `-t` option:

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

It's not recommended to modify configuration files in `/etc/letsencrypt/` but creating *(if it doesn't exist)* and modifying **cli.ini** file here is working for me. You can specify `post-hook` in this file once and it will work for all your certificates, see my current file:

```
# /etc/letsencrypt/cli.ini
max-log-backups = 0
authenticator = webroot
webroot-path = /var/www/html
post-hook = service nginx reload
text = True
```

I hope this will help future readers. Solution source is [here](https://habr.com/ru/post/318952/) *(however the article is in Russian)*

Comment: It works. there is so called `pid` file there, so the solution is just because `sudo service nginx restart` can create `/run/nginx.pid` right?

Comment: @http8086 Not sure that I understood your question. But I think the issue is certbot trying to operate with NGINX process using `.pid` file. Path to `.pid` file can be changed in conf file. After restarting NGINX `.pid` file can be located in new place. Honestly, I don't remember why I started from restarting NGINX :) The key thing is using correct `post-hook` command for reloading NGINX in `cli.ini` file and tested NGINX configuration file, of course.

Answer (score 6):

You can run this command line before run reload nginx.

```
sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

or

```
sudo nginx -c /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

then you can start nginx nomaly

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04

I've just removed post and pre hooks in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf` and changed authenticator to `nginx` - I had in two entries `standalone`.

And it is working now fine.

**Edit:**

[Recommended way](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-regenerate-renewal-config-file/58628) to update renewal config is to reissue new certificate using:

`certbot -i nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com certonly`

Comment: Just as an addition: There is a nice explanation about how to correct the .conf files in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54540470/2692283

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error...

When I installed certbot, I followed the instructions and put in a cronjob (5 3 15 * *):

```
certbot renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

this morning nginx was dead, and the log showed

```
open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

I did not connect the two, but do I understand that certbot triggers the nginx failure?

Answer (score 0):

1. `ps -ef | grep nginx`, find all nginx process
2. `sudo kill -9 xxx xxx xxx` or `sudo pkill nginx`
3. `sudo systemctl restart nginx`
4. `sudo nginx -t`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and followed a similar tack to those outlined here.

I had had `certbot` install a certificate, but it was in `certonly --nginx` mode, I supplied my own nginx serverblocks. `certbot` worked, but an nginx failure cast doubt on the accuracy of my provisioning.

This `certbot` call "restarts" nginx with a modified server block configuration, so it can answer the HTTP-01 challenges. I know this because when it fails, it will log, "nginx restart failed:" just before the `bind()` failures I'm about to show. My nginx server was down when provisioning *succeeded*.

I couldn't get `systemctl` or `service` to start it and `systemd status nginx` would only ever show "failed".

Whilst I *could* get nginx up, and serving, with `nginx -s reload` I wanted `systemd` to manage it for me.

No amount of `systemctl {start|restart|stop|quit} nginx`, would work. The `status` remained as failed and would show errors with `bind()`:

```
Oct 07 10:04:13 HostXYZ systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 07 10:04:13 HostXYZ nginx[17096]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
Oct 07 10:04:13 HostXYZ nginx[17096]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
Oct 07 10:04:13 HostXYZ nginx[17096]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
Oct 07 10:04:13 HostXYZ nginx[17096]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
```

That would repeat in `journalctl` output, 4 or 5 times.

I checked the process and saw:

```bash
:~$ ps aux | grep nginx
root       12960  0.0  0.6  77216  9816 ?        Ss   Oct06   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data   16944  0.0  0.5  77360  8604 ?        S    08:43   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

That process, which appeared to be occupying the ports needed by my `systemd` service. My `systemd` service doesn't use that `-c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. It uses:

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
```

`nginx -s stop`, and `quit` would not rid me of the rogue process. Instead they both gave the error the OP had:

```
:~$ sudo nginx -s stop
nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Both my systemd service unit and `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` gave `/run/nginx.pid` as the `PIDFile`/`pid`. For some reason, `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` wasn't creating it.

**What I needed to do:**

```bash
sudo killall nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

That knocked out the other nginx service (I think it came from `nginx -s reload` but I couldn't shut it down by the corollary command) Which looked like this:

```
:~$ sudo killall nginx
:~$ ps aux | grep nginx
john    17140  0.0  0.1   4008  2004 pts/0    S+   10:10   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
:~$ sudo systemctl start nginx
:~$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-10-07 10:10:25 UTC; 1s ago
...
:~$ ps aux | grep nginx
root       11481  0.0  0.1  76484  2588 ?        Ss   10:10   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data   11482  0.0  0.2  76876  4284 ?        S    10:10   0:00 nginx: worker process
:~$ cat /run/nginx.pid 
11481
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me due to different authenticator plugin for each domain:
one was with `authenticator = standalone`, another with `authenticator = nginx`. Also pre- post- hooks was set to both, which is also wrong, it should be used only with standalone plugin.

When I get rid of this mess, specified `authenticator = nginx` for all domains in `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/*.conf` and removed hooks -- everything starts to work smooth.