# nginx service failed (Result: exit-code) Job for nginx.service failed

Tags: nginx

I've been trying to apply an SSL to my droplet, but the nginx gives me an error when I try to execute the certbot.

```
    ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-10-19 13:50:49 UTC; 39s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 18860 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 18850 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 19 13:50:47 All-line nginx[18860]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 19 13:50:47 All-line nginx[18860]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 19 13:50:48 All-line nginx[18860]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 19 13:50:48 All-line nginx[18860]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 19 13:50:48 All-line nginx[18860]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 19 13:50:48 All-line nginx[18860]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Oct 19 13:50:49 All-line nginx[18860]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Oct 19 13:50:49 All-line systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 19 13:50:49 All-line systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 19 13:50:49 All-line systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Comment: `Address already in use`. Something is already running on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

If You use certbot, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51005440/nginx-crashing-daily-and-error-log-shows-nothing) helped me. Updating certbot and updating of letsencrypt config files.