# Nginx service that is not properly stopped by the certbot and therefore does not restart

Tags: nginx, certbot

I'm having a little trouble with my vps running with a debian. It hosts several websites, via an infrastructure based on nginx, gunicorn, django.
The sites in question have an ssl certificate managed by let's encrypt.

The problem I think comes when let's encrypt wants to renew the certificates.

**The error**

The system log when the error appears:

```
Dec 12 00:01:46 vps465872 systemd[1]: Starting Certbot...
Dec 12 00:01:49 vps465872 systemd[1]: Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 12 00:01:49 vps465872 systemd[1]: Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Dec 12 00:01:55 vps465872 certbot[600]: nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
Dec 12 00:01:56 vps465872 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 12 00:01:56 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:56 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:57 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:57 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:57 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:57 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:58 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:58 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:58 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:58 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 nginx[658]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 certbot[600]: Hook command "service nginx start" returned error code 1
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 certbot[600]: Error output from service:
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 certbot[600]: Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
Dec 12 00:01:59 vps465872 certbot[600]: See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

**The reproduction**

So be it. Let's redo the process manually. I kill everything that lies around nginx:

```
ps -ef |grep nginx
kill -9 xxxx
kill -9 xxxx
```

I relaunch nginx:

```
service nginx start
```

then everything works fine.

I do a dry-run of the certbot:

```
certbot renew --dry-run
```

and now I have the error:

```
Attempting to renew cert (xxx.fr) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/xxx.fr.conf produced an unexpected error: Problem binding to port 443: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6... Skipping.
```

**The investigation**

I look in the /run directory: the file nginx.pid no longer exists.

On the other hand, a little *ps -ef |grep nginx* tells me that the process is still running, indeed the websites are working. Therefore if I do a *nginx start service*, it outputs the address conflict error to me.

I found people on stackoverflow with the same problem as me, but the solutions don't work. But it gave me clues where to look.
[Certbot renew: nginx: [error] open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571099/certbot-renew-nginx-error-open-run-nginx-pid-failed-2-no-such-file-or)

so I'm looking:
the files /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/xxx.fr.conf contain the following hooks:

```
[renewalparams]
authenticator = standalone
installer = nginx
pre_hook = service nginx stop
post_hook = service nginx start
```

Very well. I look at the associated scripts /etc/init.d/nginx :
at the very beginning it extracts the pid via

```
PID=$(cat /etc/nginx/nginx/nginx.conf | grep -Ev' ^\s*#' | awk' BEGIN { RS="[;{}]" } { if ($1 == "pid") print $2 }' | head -n1)
```

this command works well.

to stop:

```
stop_nginx() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --retry=$STOP_SCHEDULE --pidfile $PID --name $NAME
    RETVAL="$?"
    sleep 1
    return "$RETVAL"
}
```

to start

```
start_nginx() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
        || return 1
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- \
        $DAEMON_OPTS 2>/dev/null \
        || return 2
}
```

It looks like it's good. Moreover, when the service works well with its pid, the start and stop commands work very well.

**The conclusion**

Well, that's all, here I am with a problem I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recommend to use a `webroot` mode istead of standalone mode. To renew the certificates it creates a '.well-known/acme-challenge/' in your webservers root directory.

Upside is less down time as instead of 'stop-wait-start' you just need to restart the nginx service via `post_hook`

Hope this alternative solution helps

Comment: Better still, use `service nginx reload` instead of restart.